# How to store cookies in asp.net identity (web api)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cookies

I have Asp.net web Application project with WebApi and individuals user Account.
I implemented Registration and login, and I used angularjs in front end.

Now, I need to store cookies in browser.

I'm confuse if authentication based on cookies store cookies in browser?

In my project I authenticate users based on token.

I do research but it confuse me and I did't find a clear guide to store cookies using Asp.Net Identity webApi.

Here is where is user authenticate:

```
  public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }
       /* 
   I tried the following but I get an error that Request doesn't exist

 var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
        var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
        authenticationManager.SignIn(id);

                 */

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
    }
```

I'm sorry, I'm new in Asp.net Identity.

If there is a clear guide to do this in Asp.Net Identity in WebApi (Not MVC)?

Note: I don't have LoginPath.

Comment: https://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-1  check the part 2 it may help you
https://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-2

Comment: I already read it, couldn't find what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So you have a webApi that you use to authenticate your users and when your user is authenticated you get a jwt token, Right ? and you need to save that token in a cookie so that your front-end would use to make requests.

so here is a sample code i wrote to do just that is asp core api
in my aspcore API AccountsController => Login Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var token = await _authenticationService.GenerateToken(vm);
            if (token != null)
            {
                return Ok(new
                {
                    token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                    expiration = token.ValidTo
                });
            }
            return Unauthorized();
        }
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden, new { ErrorMessage = "wrong Email or password" });
    }
```

the _authenticationService is a class that i wrote to generatae jwt token :

```
 public async Task<JwtSecurityToken> GenerateToken(LoginViewModel vm)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.Email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.Password))
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(vm.Email);
            var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);


            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration.GetSection("Secrets:SigningKey").Value));
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                 new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, vm.Email)
            };

            foreach (var roleName in userRoles)
            {
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, roleName));
            };


            if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, vm.Password))
            {
                var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        issuer: _configuration.GetSection("Secrets:issuer").Value,
                        audience: _configuration.GetSection("Secrets:audience").Value,
                        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(20),
                        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(signingKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256),
                        claims: claims);

                return token;
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

so in the code above you if you send a good credentials to your api you will get a jwt token back.
now you need to save that token in a cookie, to do that you need to create the cookie in your front-end not your web api.

so you might see this link in [angular-university](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/#step4storingandusingthejwtontheclientside)